# SwiftUI: prevent View from refreshing when presenting a sheet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have noticed that SwiftUI completely refresh view when adding `sheet`modifier.

Let's say I have View that displays random number. I expect that this value would be independent and not connected to the sheet logic (not changing every time I open/close sheet), but **every time sheet presented/dismissed Text is changing**.

Is it supposed to work so?
Am I wrong that main point of `@Sate`is to update only connected Views but not all stack?
How can I prevent my View from refreshing itself when presenting a modal?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var active = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Random text: \(Int.random(in: 0...100))")

            Button(action: { self.active.toggle() }) {
                Text("Show pop up")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $active) {
            Text("POP UP")
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. ContentView calls `onAppear()`/`onDisappear()` and `init()` only ones.

Comment: Yes, it is expected behavior. `View` is struct, value type, if any part of it changed then entire value changed.

Comment: @Asperi, did I understand you right, that _if any part of it changed then entire value changed_ works only because of `@State` property. And it's not relevant for classic (not SwiftUI) swift

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It needs to make separated condition-independent view to achieve behavior as you wish, like below

```
struct RandomView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Random text: \(Int.random(in: 0...100))")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var active = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RandomView()

            Button(action: { self.active.toggle() }) {
                Text("Show pop up")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $active) {
            Text("POP UP")
        }
    }
}
```

In this case `RandomView` is not rebuilt because is not dependent on `active` state.

Comment: As usual, Asperi is correct. This article gives a few additional clear examples of views being inter-dependent, and how to factor them: https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/swiftui-why-to-write-custom-views-for-better-performance-561962f1c268

Comment: Just to add, for more complicated use cases, use the `Equatable` protocol on a SwiftUI view with the `.equatable()` modifier.

Comment: ...the culmination of a couple of wasted days trying to figure out why my UI was completely updating every time a TextField value was modified, then trying to fix it. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 5):

Asperi sad :

> View is struct, value type, if any part of it changed then entire
>   value changed

He is absolutely right! But for that we have state properties. When the view is recreated, the value of state doesn't change.

This should work, as you expected

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var active = false
    @State var number = Int.random(in: 0 ... 100)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Random text: \(number)")

            Button(action: { self.active.toggle() }) {
                Text("Show pop up")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $active) {
            Text("POP UP")
        }
    }
}
```

What is the advantage? For simple things, the state / binding is the best solution, without any doubt.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var randomnumber: Int
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.randomnumber = Int.random(in: 0 ... 100)
        }) {
            Text("Generate new random number")
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var active = false
    @State var number = Int.random(in: 0 ... 100)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Random text: \(number)")

            Button(action: { self.active.toggle() }) {
                Text("Show pop up")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $active) {
            SheetView(randomnumber: self.$number)
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Now you can dismiss the sheet with or without generating new random number. No external model is required ...

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, but this question is a little bit simplified. In real project I have List with of custom view rows with `@State` object as datasource. And my problem was running `init()` method for row many times. Datasource didn't change, but I don't need to re-initing cells each time sheet is opened/closed, because I have some logic connected to cell `init()` method.

Comment: @DmytroPashkov  in that case, don't use state. Use some model, separated from user interface.  In general, answer the question: do i need some binding in my view? if not, i don't need  state property wrapper ...