# Memoization in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I come from React where I use `useMemo` to make sure some computation isn't executed too often. How would I do something like that in SwiftUI?

Consider this example:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    var records: [Record]

    var body: some View {
        Text("expensive summary: \(self.expensiveSummary)")
    }

    var expensiveSummary: String {
        // based on records, return string
        // containing a summary of records

        return ""
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make sure my `expensiveSummary` is only called when my array of Records changed?

Comment: We can assume a parent view is passing in `records` and that changes.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can create a wrapper view as `Equatable`.
(Perhaps, can we use `EquatableView` or `.equatable()` modifier?)

```swift
struct UseMemo<KeyType: Equatable, ViewType: View>: View, Equatable {
    let key: KeyType
    let content: (KeyType) -> ViewType

    var body: some View {
        content(key)
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: UseMemo, rhs: UseMemo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.key == rhs.key
    }
}
```

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State var records: [Int] = (Array<Int>)(1...10000)
    @State var other = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Update other", action: { self.other.toggle() })
            Text("Other: \(String(other))") // This will be called everytime

            Button("Update records", action: { self.records.append(1) })
            
            UseMemo(key: records) { keys in
                // This is not called even if updated "other"
                // This is called when updates "records"
                Text("expensive summary: \(expensiveSummary)")
            }
            
            // This will be called everytime
            Text("expensive summary: \(expensiveSummary)")
        }
    }
    
    var expensiveSummary: String {
        String(records.randomElement()!)
    }
}
```

Followings are helped me.

- [SwiftUI — Why should you write as many custom views for better performance](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/swiftui-why-to-write-custom-views-for-better-performance-561962f1c268)
- [SwiftUI: prevent View from refreshing when presenting a sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60112172/9578323)

Answer (score 1):

This is built-in as `EquatableView`.

```
struct MyView: EquatableView { ... }
```

This will only recompute `body` if its properties (`records` in this case) actually change, which will prevent `expensiveSummary` from being reevaluated.

This won't avoid multiple evaluations of `expensiveSummary` *inside* of `body`. If you need to cache that kind of information, you generally should create a local variable (though sometimes function builder syntax won't allow this without extracting parts of the code into a separate function), or compute a property in `init`.

As a matter of style, I would recommend against computed properties ever being expensive to evaluate. This is confusing, because property syntax generally suggests the operation is cheap. Instead I would recommend this be a function or computed once in `init`.